# How to store a route in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, push-notification

I'm trying to implement a notification system in ASP.NET Core. I've started with a `Notification` class for each user:

```
class Notification
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have an `AssessmentsController` with a `Create` action that creates an assessment for specific users. Once it is created, I want to notify all the users for whom the assessment was created.

```
class AssessmentsController : Controller
{
   public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateViewModel model)
   {
         // Create assessment for some users
         _context.Add(assessment);
         
         
         List<Notification> notifications = new();
         foreach(var user in users)
         {
             Notification notif = new() 
             { 
               User = assessment.User, 
               Title = "New Assessment",
               Description = "You have a new assessment scheduled for you" 
             }
             notifications.Add(notif);
         }
         await _context.AddRangeAsync(notifications);
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); 
         return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
   }
}
```

When a user clicks on the notification, I want to take the user to a specific page. How do I associate the notification with the route of that page? This is a very watered down version of how the notification would look like:

```cshtml
@model Notification

    <h5> @Model.Title </h5>
    <p>  @Model.Description </p>
    <a @* what to include here? *@> View </a>
}
```

One way I could think of is adding the following properties to `Notification`:

```
public string Area { get; set; }
public string Controller { get; set; }
public string Action { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, string> Params { get; set; }
```

Then the following would work:

```cshtml
<a 
    asp-area="@notif.Area" 
    asp-controller="@notif.Controller" 
    asp-action="@notif.Action" 
    asp-all-route-data="@notif.Params"> View </a>
```

But I think this just works for MVC and is not comprehensive. Also, in the future if the name of the page ends up changing by chance, the notification will be useless.

I've never worked with notifications before. Can someone help me with this? How are notifications usually implemented? I'm currently not using anything like SignalR. It's all server-side at the moment. I'm using Identity and Entity Framework Core 5 with PostgreSQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0) might help. If your app is all server-side how are you going to push notifications to users? I mean you can check for notifications on every page load if you don't need instant notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can take a look into this helper method for url generation, which receives controller and action name and use it to send redirect url

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_UrlHelperExtensions_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_IUrlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_Object_

But it won't be a good idea to store it for a long time, because your controllers and actions routes can change.
It can be good if you send it once with SignalR

If you need to store it and then fetch from DB, you can probably store some ids of your assessment in Notification model and then dynamically generate url from it and information about the controller when you render, without storing controller name and action there. You can also generate some route data from it manually in code.
This way if you will change route to your controller, links will be generated correctly. And if your controller name will change, you will only need to also change some part of your code, which is easier then changing links or controller name in database